# Windows Store App (8.1): INotifyPropertyChanged Must Be Top Level?

Tags: c#, data-binding, windows-runtime

Why does this:

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _bp;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged; 

    public string BindableProperty
    {
        get { return _bp; }

        set
        {
            _bp = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged( [CallerMemberName] string caller = "" )
    {
        var eventHandler = PropertyChanged;

        if( eventHandler != null )
            eventHandler( this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs( caller ) );
    }
}
```

bind correctly in a Windows Store app Page (i.e., the binding target is listening to the PropertyChanged event, as can be verified by breaking in NotifyPropertyChanged and seeing that eventHandler is not null). But this:

```
public interface IViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    string BindableProperty { get; set; }
}

public class ViewModel : IViewModel
{
    private string _bp;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged; 

    public string BindableProperty
    {
        get { return _bp; }

        set
        {
            _bp = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged( [CallerMemberName] string caller = "" )
    {
        var eventHandler = PropertyChanged;

        if( eventHandler != null )
            eventHandler( this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs( caller ) );
    }
}
```

fails to bind (i.e., eventHandler is always null, and the binding target never reflects updates to BindableProperty).

I read someplace that since WinRT isn't managed code it doesn't support reflection. So instead some component of the OS builds a hidden object, when a managed app starts, storing type information which would otherwise be obtained through reflection. The behavior I'm noticing looks like whatever type scanning process is used isn't smart enough to trace back through a chain of derived interface definitions.

So is my theory correct? Or am I missing something else which is causing the problem?

**Edit**

Thanks, Rob, for replying. To provide a bit more context, I am updating the properties within an asynchronous method called from within a couple of asynchronous event handlers (e.g., private async void navigationHelper_LoadState( object sender, LoadStateEventArgs e ), private async void btnSeek_Click( object sender, RoutedEventArgs e ).

More importantly, when I went back and re-ran the what I thought was the same code this morning everything worked as expected, even with the "dervied" interface definition. So obviously I changed something along the way that I don't remember.

Given my recent experience I now suspect I'm having a problem with the way I'm writing and calling various asynchronous methods. It's a new area to me, and I've noticed all sorts of run-time difficulties if, for example, one forgets to "await" an asynchronous operation. The app will still compile, but the run-time behavior is very different.

Comment: How are you binding to this? It worked when I set this ViewModel as my page's DataContext and bound a TextBlock to BindingProperty. The eventHandler was not null and updates to BindableProperty showed up in the TextBlock

Comment: See the edit, Rob. Thanks again for replying.